# Rails Twitter OAuth Strategy with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, oauth-ruby, twitter-oauth

I have been searching to figure out how exactly to use the oauthable module in the Devise gem for Rails 3. I have come across a couple of questions on here that seem correct, but I was unable to get the implementation working. My end goal is to have both Twitter and Facebook authentication through Devise in my Rails 3 application. Right now I am struggling with what I thought was the "example" in the warden strategy list. I have got this far.

Inside of my devise initalizer I have the following blocks of code in, what I believe, the appropriate places.

```
manager.oauth(:twitter) do |twitter|
  twitter.consumer_secret = '[secret]'
  twitter.consumer_key  = '[key]'
  twitter.options :site => 'http://twitter.com'
end
manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :twitter_oauth        

Warden::OAuth::access_token_user_finder(:twitter) do |access_token|
  User.find_or_create_by(:token => access_token.token, :secret => access_token.secret).tap do |user|
     user ||= User.create!(:access_token => access_token.token, :secret => access_token.secret)
  end
end
```

I have placed a link on one of my views but all I am getting is an error, OAuth 401 Unauthorized, is this something from Twitter or am I completely missing a step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you seen [OmniAuth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for Twitter, FB and other social network authentication integration into devise?

The [last two](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) [railscast episodes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) show off an integration.

[OmniSocial](http://icelab.com.au/articles/welcome-to-the-omnisocial/) is another solution built on top of the two.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm fairly new to Rails development, but Ryan's screencasts are a gold mine and seem to crop up every time I want to do something new.